# Is there a reversal in the following sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> This mapping also helps better support page parameters.

Is the above sentence the same as this one?

> This mapping also helps support page parameters better.

The original sentence is extracted from the tech book '*Silverlight 4 in action*'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first sentence, *better* modifies *support*. In the second sentence, *better* either modifies *help* or *support*. In this case, I don't believe it makes any difference to the meaning (this mapping also improves the support for page parameters). But consider the sentence:

> In the future, I will help you bake your lemon cakes better.

This could mean that I was a bad helper, and I'll be a better one in the future. Or it could mean that you did not do a good job baking the lemon cakes this time, and next time I will help you do a better job.